# add class to parent li when submenu is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having a problem here despite googling for hours. 
 i have a menu which has submenus.

```
<div class="themenu">
    <ul>

      <li>Link 1               //Want to add class catactive here when the following submenu is active

        <div class="thesubmenu">

           <ul>
             <li class="subcat-active">submenu1</li>
           </ul>

        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried using this query but its not happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                if($('.thesubmenu ul li').hasClass('subcat-active')){
                    $(this).parent('.themenu ul li').addClass('cat-active');
                } 
            });
```

Comment: `console.log($(this).parent('.themenu ul li'));` and check your browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to write this but there is no need to iterate (`.each()`) or use `.hasClass()` which slow down this simple call.

Simply select the `li` items with `.subcat-active`, then use `closest('li')` to find the closest `li` ancestor and add the class. You need to use `.parent()` first because `closest()` includes the starting element which is also a `li`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thesubmenu ul li.subcat-active').parent().closest('li').addClass('cat-active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ehvqzjh/1/

Comment: finally, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.subcat-active').each(function () {
       $(this).parents('li').eq(0).addClass('cat-active');
   });
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/z232j2f4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.thesubmenu ul li.subcat-active').each(function(){
        $(this).parent().closest('li').addClass('cat-active');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bpkpn6b5/

Comment: `closest` includes the current element, so `parent` is needed. `each` is really not necessary.

Comment: Yes I forgot about it including itself, i thought I'd deleted the comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yx2695e8/1/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     if ($('.thesubmenu ul li').hasClass('subcat-active')) {
          $('.thesubmenu ul li').parents('li:eq(0)').addClass('cat-active');
     } 
});
```